# Interacting with trade/order function which require sha3 hash

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, metamask

I'm currently building a dapp that use both of theses functions :

```
function order(address tokenGet, uint amountGet, address tokenGive, uint amountGive, uint expires, uint nonce) {
    bytes32 hash = sha256(this, tokenGet, amountGet, tokenGive, amountGive, expires, nonce);
    orders[msg.sender][hash] = true;
    Order(tokenGet, amountGet, tokenGive, amountGive, expires, nonce, msg.sender);
  }

  function trade(address tokenGet, uint amountGet, address tokenGive, uint amountGive, uint expires, uint nonce, address user, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s, uint amount) {
    //amount is in amountGet terms
    bytes32 hash = sha256(this, tokenGet, amountGet, tokenGive, amountGive, expires, nonce);
    if (!(
      (orders[user][hash] || ecrecover(sha3("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32", hash),v,r,s) == user) &&
      block.number <= expires &&
      safeAdd(orderFills[user][hash], amount) <= amountGet
    )) throw;
    tradeBalances(tokenGet, amountGet, tokenGive, amountGive, user, amount);
    orderFills[user][hash] = safeAdd(orderFills[user][hash], amount);
    Trade(tokenGet, amount, tokenGive, amountGive * amount / amountGet, user, msg.sender);
  }
```

I'm able to list the multiple events arguments in Order, but I'm not able to generate the data let's say for checking if order exist.

Is that the correct what to generate the hash? I suppose this (`bytes32 hash = sha256(this)`) is the sender address?

```
var orderhash = web3.sha3(user, tokenGet, amountGet, tokenGive, amountGive, expires, nonce);
```

EDIT: I understood that web3.sha3 don't act as the sha3 from solidity. Still, I'm not able to get it work the correct way and I can't install node module

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of `web3.sha3` is solidity [`keccak256`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#mathematical-and-cryptographic-functions). The solidity function `sha256` is a completely different hash, and it doesn't have an equivalent with web3.